# Convert Sql to EF in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I need to convert an sql query to Linq query
my sql query is

```
select *,SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' + cast(CT_LBookIssue.BK_id as varchar(max)) 
 from CT_LBookIssue FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) as BK_id 
 from CM_LBookIssue
```

here CM_LBookIssue is the parent table and CT_LBookIssue is the child table. Lbl_id is the primary key of CM_LBookIssue. But i need to show the final output as a single row.The sql query i gave here returns a single row with BK_id in CT_LBookIssue as comma separated.Bk_id is one of the fields in   CT_LBookIssue

Comment: who is stopping you from doing it?

Comment: what is CT_LBookIssue.BK_id ? can you post a typical example of what would be stored in there?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
var result = (from ct in context.CT_LBookIssue
    join cm in context.CM_LBookIssue on ct.SomeId equals cm.SomeId 
    select ct);
```

Note: replace `SomeId` in the above with whatever columns you use to join these tables.

Note also that EF returns XML columns as `string`, so `ct.BK_id` would be returned as `string`.

Is this what you wanted?